Why is typescript showing error ony in case of partial and record not for mapped types?
In the code, when I create a map type of user it's working fine. But the Partial<Record<keyof User, number>> is doing the same thing but throwing {firstName: 2} is not assignable error?
type Person = {firstName: string}

const foo = <User extends Person>(user: User) => {
    let user1: { [K in keyof User]?: number };
    user1 = { firstName: 1 };

    let user2: Partial<Record<keyof User, number>>;
    user2 = { firstName: 2} // <----- error
}


Please [edit] this to be a [mre] where you declare your types, so we can paste it into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing. (specifically, what's Person?) Until that happens this question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

(see prev comment) I suspect it's the same reason as this comment about circularity; evaluation of type aliases like Partial<T> are deferred for generics, and TS can't be sure that they are compatible because it doesn't analyze it fully enough. I can't find a more targeted github issue, though, so you might want to file one to get a definitive answer, and then we can put that answer here when we get it.

@jcalz it is indeed due to TS being unsure of what the generics can be. foo<{firstName: "John"} & null> will be an issue, hence ts is showing errors. Thanks for your help.
